# javascript - retrieve string right after a specific string and before the next colon

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in learning javascript, need to retrieve a specific part of value from the string.

below is the format of string provided by my teammates, they are a set of parameter and its value separated by a colon.

how can I retrieve the value, once input the parameter name, then return the value just before the next colon?

```
string = "productCat:Wine:country:Australia:year:2000:type:white wine:"
```

example:

- if input 'productCat', then return 'Wine'
- if input 'country', then return 'Australia'
- if input 'year', then return '2000'
- if input 'type', then return 'white wine'

thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and share what you tried already to solve that task (code, what doesn't work as expected, error messages, ...) by pressing the [edit] link and adjusting your question.

Comment: While what you're asking is certainly achievable, I'd be tempted to also go back to your teammates and ask if they could provide the information in a nicer form - for instance a JSON dictionary would be ideal here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example. Just split the string, then look for the next index if something is found.
But this is not very smart.

```js
const string = 'productCat:Wine:country:Australia:year:2000:type:white wine';

const findNext = (data, str) => {
  const array = data.split(':');
  const i = array.indexOf(str);
  if(i >= 0) return array[i+1];
}

console.log(findNext(string, 'productCat'));
console.log(findNext(string, 'country'));
```

Here is what I would do if I were you:

```js
const string = 'productCat:Wine:country:Australia:year:2000:type:white wine';

const parseString = str => {
  const array = str.split(':');
  const result = {};
  for(let i = 0; i<array.length; i=i+2) {
    result[array[i]] = array[i+1];
  }
  return result;
}

const result = parseString(string);
console.log(result);
console.log(result.country);
console.log(result.year);
```

Just parse the string and build an object you'll use easily later ;)

Comment: @judy feel free to upvote if it helped or mark it has accepted if it solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that will be compatible with older browsers.

```js
var string = "productCat:Wine:country:Australia:year:2000:type:white wine:"

function getPart(string, input) {
  var parts = string.split(":");

  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i = i + 2) {
    if (parts[i] == input) {
      return parts[i+1];
    }
  }
}

console.log(getPart(string, "productCat"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First split your string into array of strings using split() function

```
  string="productCat:Wine:country:Australia:year:2000:type:white wine:"
 var array=string.split(":");
```

Second according to input return the value which is index+

```
return var x=array[array.indexOf(input)+1];
```

Comment: thanks so much for your explanation,  noted the way to split and find the next value :)